# Download UIImage data on different queue and resizes when user scrolls in the tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage, grand-central-dispatch

Downloading the blogpost from `JSON data` and storing in a custom `class called BlogPost`

I am encountering an issue that can only be described with the screenshots below. But basically, I want the images to be fill the entire cell like the after shot. However this is only happening when i scroll and then it resizes to the small thumbnail when i stop scrolling?

How can I fix this issue and make the cell have a full background? Thanks

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
BlogTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

BlogPost *blogPost = [self.blogPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

__block NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] init];
__block UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
__block UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];

if ( [blogPost.thumbnail isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogPost.thumbnailURL];
    image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    bgImage = image;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            bgImage = [bgImage applyLightEffect];
            cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];
        });
    });
}

cell.title.text = blogPost.title;
[cell.title sizeToFit];

return cell;
}
```

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: How have you created your custom cell? You might be missing autosizing masks or layout constraints for the image view inside the custom cell.

Comment: I only have a custom label for my custom cell, i figured setting the background of the cell was enough?

Comment: This is the only code in my custom cell subclass: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;

Comment: Try setting contentMode of imageView to UIContentModeRedraw.

Comment: Besides comments above, it is a better way to use SDWebImage (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to load images asynchronously .